# Convergence in distribution and almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, weak-convergence, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ a probability space and $Z_n, Z$ defined on it and taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, such that $Z_n \to Z$, $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely. Let $g_n, g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable, such that
$$
g_n(Z_n) \stackrel{d}{\to} g(Z).
$$
Question: Does this imply that
$$
g_n(Z_n) \to g(Z)
$$
$\mathbb{P}$-almost surely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, $Z_n = Z\simeq \mathcal N(0,1)$, $g_n(x) = -x$, $g(x) = x$.

Comment: Great, thank you so much